How to automate Ansible SSH login with Duo MFA for sudo access
The problem:
I'm trying to run Ansible on a Mac to remotely configure a linux (ubuntu) server that requires MFA access for sudo usage. My goal is to keep the MFA in place (as required by our security team) but enable us to use Ansible after the MFA process has authenticated. I've found a related query that describes how to do this with ControlFile in ssh: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64671608/1910490
Just to explain, the process to manually use sudo (currently) is:
# login using ssh key
> ssh server_name 
# run sudo
> sudo su

$ sudo su
Duo two-factor login for <username>

Enter a passcode or select one of the following options:

 1. SMS passcodes to XXX-XXX-<number>

Passcode or option (1-1):

> 1

New SMS passcodes sent.

Duo two-factor login for <user>

Enter a passcode or select one of the following options:

 1. SMS passcodes to XXX-XXX-<number> (next code starts with: 1)

> <code>


Success. Logging you in...

At this point, sudo access is granted for the session.
What I've tried
I've attempted to use shared control file for SSH to allow one session to gain access to another session which has already completed the sudo MFA process. This would in theory allow me to run Ansible in another terminal with sudo access and avoid the whole MFA issue.
I've configured .ssh/config like so:
Host *
        ControlMaster auto
        ControlPath ~/.ssh/shared.%h.pipe
        ControlPersist 10m

After opening a session, the control file does get created, and I believe the shared connection is getting used.
But when I try to use sudo from another terminal, I still get the sudo MFA prompt.
Is what I'm attempting possible, or is there a better way?

Not related to the issue you are facing, but just FYI there's no need to run sudo su, just run su or sudo -i; why run two commands when one will do?

This is the result of specific configuration on the target server. If you don't want MFA enabled for sudo you'll need to talk with your systems administrators about it. Working around the security posture seems inappropriate at best (for example, if you have sudo rights you could create an executable that drops your UID into a root shell - but should you do this)

@ChrisDavies I don't have a problem with MFA being enabled on the account, I was hoping there would be a way to perform the MFA and then allow ansible to use that same session after I've authenticated.

Oh I see. I didn't realise that's what you were trying to achieve. It seemed that you were trying to bypass the MFA for Ansible. Maybe make it as clear as that in your question?

Thanks for the suggestion! I've updated the post. Hopefully it is more clear now.
